# как сохранить canvas как картинку

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, html2canvas

[image: Это страница]
[image: это то что сохраняется]

```
<div id="imagee">
    <img src="image.png">
    <p>asd</p>
</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="exportimage()" >SAVE</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function exportimage() {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('imagee'), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                    saveAs(blob ,"image.png");
                }, "image/png");
                var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                return img.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
            };
        });
    };
</script>
```

сохраняет canvas но не загружает картинку, как можно решить данную проблему ?

Comment: Нужно рисовать картинку в canvas.

Comment: @ИльяБизунов может код глянешь после вопроса ? если не знаешь не надо просто что-то писать

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

Comment: @ИльяБизунов спасибо, это я знаю, а как еще текст сохранить которое в <p>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И картинку, и текст **нужно рендерить в canvas**:

В случаей с картинкой:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("scream");
ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
```

В случае с текстом:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "48px serif";
ctx.fillText("Hello world", 10, 50);
```

Писать вот так нельзя (точнее можно, но это не будет рендером в канвас):

```
<div id="imagee">
    <img src="image.png">
    <p>asd</p>
    <div class='another'></div>
</div>
```